# Pass setState function as callback to onChangeText

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Can I directly pass `setState` to `onChangeText` in `TextInput` component instead of passing a callback function and calling `setState` function in a callback? e.g

```
const [state, setState] = useState(initialState);
/*Other code logic*/
<TextInput onChange={setState}/>
```

Comment: You can, but you‘re missing out on the event object that you would otherwise recieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can directly trigger functions. E.g.:

```
const [state, setState] = useState(initialState);
/* Other code logic */
<TextInput onChangeInput={(evt) => {
    setState(evt.target.value)
} />
```

Comment: Sorry I ment to say onChange, not onChangeInput